# Almacenar fila en variable

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, imaginemos que tenemos una tabla llamada Tipo y imaginemos que quiero obtener solamente el elemento con valor de `id` de 3.
En ese caso, usaria esto:

```
$tipo=Tipo::where('id',3)->get();
```

Esto me devolveria un vector de un solo elemento con la fila de Tipo cuyo valor de `id` sea igual a 3.
Pero quiero que este directamente en una variable para no tener que estar poniendo `$tipo[0]` para hacer cualquier operación con esta fila.
¿Como lo logro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay 2 problemas con lo que intentas hacer primero la consulta para obtener el resultado que deseas es

```
$tipo = Tipo::where('id','=',3)->first();
```

Te falta el `=` en tu consulta, ademas de que estas usando `get()` que siempre devolvera el resultado en un array ya que este se usa cuando se desean sacar mas de un resultado.

En tu caso tienes que hacer uso de `first()`, que devuelve un unico registro. Asi podras obtener los datos de tu tabla, por ejemplo:

```
$tipo->nombre;
```

Comment: El símbolo de igual no es necesario, igual si lo omites funciona

Comment: @shadow gracias por la aclaratoria hermano, eso lo deconocia

Comment: Si, he usado $tipo=Tipo::where('id',$r->elemento)->first(); y me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta que fue aceptada como correcta, funciona, pero podría simplificarse y  mejorarse un poco ademas de que la parte de la afirmación de requerir el "=" es falsa, al igual que no es necesario la utilización de where('id','3'), ya que para eso se tiene un comando especifico find(), con lo cual se podría escribir de forma mas limpia y directa.

```
$tipo = Tipo::find(3);
```

Adicional a eso, la parte de colocar el '=' es importante recordarla, porque con ella se puede utilizar el resto de los símbolos (<, >, =).

```
Tipo::where('id','<',4)->get(); //(listado de todos los tipos con de menores a 4)
```

Comment: Pues tambien esta opción sirve.